# GraphQL query on Embedded/Nested Field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, graphql, schema

How to specify a query condition on fields in an embedded/nested document in MongoDB using GraphQL ?

In mongo shell I can easily get the document by

```
db.users.find({ 'contacts.phone': '8148*****' } ).pretty();
```

Which will fetch me the record

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c93c0601a29f5183929c02c"),
        "name" : "Athul",
        "contacts" : {
                "address" : "Some address",
                "phone" : "8148*****",
                "email" : "***@live.com"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```

On my GraphQL **Schema** I have defined the query as mentioned below

```
...
input ContactsInput {
    address: String
    phone: String
    email: String
}

input userInput {
  name: String
  contacts: ContactsInput
}

type RootQuery {
  users(user: userInput): [User!]!
}
....
```

The **Resolver** for users is

```
...
const User = require('../../models/user');
...
    users: async args => {
        try{
            const query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args.user));
            const userList = await User.find(query);

            if(!userList) {
                throw new Error("No user found");
            }

            return userList;
        } catch(err){
            throw err;
        }
    }
...
```

*(It works fine if I search with the name)*

And in GraphiQL I'm trying to get the same record by the below query

```
query{
  users(user: {contacts: {
    phone: "8148*****" 
  }}){
    name
    contacts{
      email
      phone
    }
  }
}
```

with which I'm not able to get the same record.

Because at the back end its executing

```
db.users.find({ contacts: { phone: '8148405590' } });
```

which is not equivalent to

```
db.users.find({ 'contacts.phone': '8148*****' } );
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide your resolver for `users`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniels I have updated the question with resolver for users.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to build the query object before sending it to `mongodb`.

You can try something like:

```
const tempQuery = {'contacts.phone': args.user.contacts.phone}

const query = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempQuery));
```

You just have to make sure that all the values(`user.contacts.phone`) exist in the input, and if you want to have other queries you have to write all different combinations (ex: `contacts.email`).

> Otherwise you could have a look into this blog post about [GraphQL to MongoDB](https://blog.solutotlv.com/graphql-to-mongodb-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-generated-query-apis/) and the library [graphql-to-mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-to-mongodb), but to implement it you might have to refactor a bit of your code.

Comment: Is there any alternative for the same ? otherwise ill have to handle queries for contacts.email and contacts.address also in the same way.

Comment: @AthulMR I updated my answer with and external tool that could potentially solve your issue.